# Can I use FieldArray alongside useFormik hook?

Tags: reactjs, formik

In my form component, I want to use FieldArray with useFormik hook. When I try to do that I get `TypeError: _this$props2$formik is undefined` error.

Should I switch to class component or can I somehow inject formik to FieldArray? Or is there a way to do that?

```js
const MyForm = ({openPanel}) => {
    const intl = useIntl();

    const formData = useSelector(state => state.form[Forms.SOURCE_EDIT]);

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            style: formData ? formData.style : '',
            layers: formData ? formData.layers : [],
        },
        validationSchema: createValidationSchema(),
        onSubmit: async values => {
            // ...
        },
    });

    const {
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        handleSubmit,
        isSubmitting,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
    } = formik;

    return (
        <div className={'center-flex'}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {/* ... */}
                <FieldArray
                    name={'layers'}
                    render={arrayHelpers => (
                        <div>
                            {values.layers.map((layer, index) => (
                                <div key={index}>{layer.name}</div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    )}
                />
                <Button
                    large
                    intent={Intent.PRIMARY}
                    fill
                    loading={isSubmitting}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                    type={'submit'}>
                    {intl.formatMessage(messages.next)}
                </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated in formik docs: **Be aware that `<Field>`, `<FastField>`, `<ErrorMessage>`, `connect()`, and `<FieldArray>` will NOT work with `useFormik()` as they all require React Context.
You've to wrap your form in `Formik` component in order to use these components as they are using formik context internally. For reference: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useFormik

Comment: Yeah I just read these lines in the docs too. I'm gonna stick a note on my monitor written "Read the Docs" on it. Thank you for your answer, sorry for the silly question.

Comment: It happens, no worries :)

Comment: Curious if you guys found out a way to make it work with `useFormik`

Answer (score 50):

Probably a bit late, but you can use FormikProvider which takes useFormik value as a prop.

```
const formik = useFormik()
....
<FormikProvider value={formik}>
  <FieldArray name="" render={() => (...) />
</FormikProvider>
```

Comment: all part of the formik package `import { useFormik, FormikProvider, FieldArray } from "formik";`

Answer (score -1):

You could also use

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#symmetricDifference or https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#xor

```
const { values, handleSubmit, handleChange, handleBlur, setFieldValue, errors } = useFormik({

const handleBerthTypeChange = React.useCallback<NonNullable<CheckboxProps["onChange"]>>(
  (e) => {
    setFieldValue("berthTypes", symmetricDifference(values.berthTypes ?? [], [e.target.name]));
  },
  [values, setFieldValue],
);


<Checkbox
  checked={values.berthTypes?.includes(code) ?? false}
  onChange={handleBerthTypeChange}
  name={code}
/>
```